# How to start a stopwatch with a loop and end when it ends in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

So I need to start a stopwatch with the push of a button which will also start a loop. How do I stop the stopwatch when the loop completes? Example below.

```
Private Sub btnStart...
    n = 0
    While n < 1001
        n += 1
        (Contents of loop go here)
    End While
    Stop stopwatch
    lbl1.Text = stopwatchvalue
```

Sorry if that doesn't make any sense (I'm fairly new to this all). If there is anything I can do to help, I'm all ears.

Thank you all so much, SO is always super helpful with this all.

Comment: That would work, in theory. Are you aware of the `StopWatch` class? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start and stop a stopwatch and then read out the elapsed time in milliseconds like this.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    sw.Start()
    Dim n As Integer = 0
    Do While n < 1001
        n += 1
        '(Contents of loop go here)
    Loop
    sw.Stop()
    lbl1.Text = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you for the quick and accurate reply. It was much easier than I had seen from Googling around, sometimes you just need an expert to clear things up!